# Can I force an object to be passed as "ByVal" (as a copy) in a call in .NET?

Tags: vb.net, object, pass-by-value

In the VB.NET code below I want to add three persons to a list of persons. I thought that I could use the same person-object over and over again and simply change it's name before next Add-call. I was hoping that each call should copy the object and add that copy to the list... But I end up with a list of three "Kim". It seems that the list elements refers to the same object.

```
Class Person
    Public Name As String
End Class

Sub Foo()
    Dim Persons as New List(Of Person)
    Dim aPerson As New Person

    aPerson.Name = "John"
    Persons.Add(aPerson)
    aPerson.Name = "Emma"
    Persons.Add(aPerson)
    aPerson.Name = "Kim"
    Persons.Add(aPerson)
End Sub
```

Can I force that `aPerson` is copied in each Add-call? Or do I need to create separate objects for John, Emma and Kim?

Comment: `Or do I need to create separate objects for John, Emma and Kim?` Yes you have to

Comment: you should give different objects.

Comment: All reference types, i.e. classes, behave that way.  If `Person` was a structure then the code you show would have worked because adding to the list would create a copy.  That might make it seem like using structures over classes is a good idea but it's not.  Classes work that way for a number of reasons and using structures where classes are appropriate can cause a number of problems.  Structures have their uses but that's generally only for small, immutable types.  Classes are and should be used the vast majority of the time.  It may seem odd but you'll get used to it.

Comment: But why isn't the reference to the object destroyed when aPerson is detstroyed after End Sub. Somewhere there seems to exist a copy of the object after all... a copy that exists after the origin object is destroyed...?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing isn't good practice as you shouldn't use a class that way.

If your names come from a source like a list you could use a `For Each` loop.

```
Dim MyNames As New List(Of String)
MyNames.Add("John")
MyNames.Add("Emma")
MyNames.Add("Kim")
For Each person_name As String In MyNames
    Dim aPerson As New Person
    aPerson.Name = person_name 
    Persons.Add(aPerson)
Next
```

This approach could be very practical if the data comes from a file, SQL request or JSON for example.

Otherwise you would just have:

```
Dim Persons as New List(Of Person)
Dim aPerson As New Person
Dim bPerson As New Person
Dim cPerson As New Person
aPerson.Name = "John"
Persons.Add(aPerson)
bPerson.Name = "Emma"
Persons.Add(bPerson)
cPerson.Name = "Kim"
Persons.Add(cPerson)
```

Comment: `For` should be `For Each`. Would submit an edit but its under character limit and the rest of the answer is great.

Comment: @AFriend Haha thanks I totally forgot to add it and didn't notice when posting